# Copy/Paste Qgis Plugin or derive new Plugin from existing one

Tags: qgis-plugins, copy

I created a Python Plugin for QGIS and I want to experiment with various versions of this plugin. Is there an easy way to copy/paste a plugin or to create a plugin from another plugin? ( Otherwise one should have to repeat manually the steps of developing the plugin, or copy/paste the plugin folder and rename the file names and all include statements)

Comment: See [here](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/plugins.html) for documentation on developing plugins for qgis.

Comment: Wouldn't you just have to rename the folder and some info in the metadata.txt. Maybe also the parts that add the plugin to the menu. Other than that you would not have to go ahead and rename every single method etc.